# android use the camera app and private storage

Tags: security, camera, private

I am trying to use the sample code at
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

to take pictures that WILL NOT show up in gallery or get shared. Google's example missed this part of the demo.

I followed the example: My code is at:
https://github.com/tomha2014/SecureCameraIntent/tree/master

Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/thackbarth.com.securecameraintent/files/Pictures

I have all the read/write external permissions in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure folders in this path exist.

```
thackbarth.com.securecameraintent/files/Pictures
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this:
'code
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if ( !storageDir.exists() )
        {
            if (!storageDir.mkdir())
                Log.e(TAG, "createImageFile: direct create failed" );
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "createImageFile: directory exists");
        }
'
it tells me dir exists even on first run. BTW; using ADB I do not see it. So I think your right!

Comment: I just checked and the file is created and image is saved to that folder (YEA!) but loading it to display says file not found error.  ;

Answer (score 0):

YEA! I found it

In the google sample code found at
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

There is a line of of code that looks like:
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();

That create a file uri, the bitmap decode:
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

Wants a path to the file Take off the "file:" and it it works.....

That was a lot of hours wasted, if Google would have just provided that code in the sample linked to that page.
In any case, I am working on a sample that uses that code for Android 6
can be found at:
https://github.com/tomha2014/SecureCameraIntent